# How to convert a given data value to camel case without using INITCAP function in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle

Input: RAKE'SH RE'DD'Y

Output(using INITCAP function) : Rake'Sh Re'Dd'Y

Expected output : Rake'sh Re'dd'y

INPUT 2: RAKESH REDDY

Output(using INITCAP function) : Rakesh Reddy

Expected output : Rakesh Reddy

The above input and input 2 should have same functionality

Can anyone help me with this ????

Comment: Oracle supports character sets with accented characters, why are you storing them as combinations of letter + apostrophe in the first place? Use an appropriate character set, then Initcap will work as intended.

Comment: @mathguy Why do you assume that the OP's string should have accents? The name `Ce'nedra O'Brien` has apostrophes and not accents.

Comment: @MT0 - I am not familiar with the name Ce'nedra, but I have seen O'Brien before - and it is never capitalized as O'brien. In these situations I expect that O'Brien is actually correct and shouldn't be rendered as O'brien. (A quick and dumb Google search shows Ce'nedra as either Ce'Nedra or as Cenedra without an apostrophe; I don't see it capitalized the way you have it.) Initcap will actually return the correct values in these cases.

Comment: @mathguy My point was not regarding the "correct" capitalisation for names but on your assumption that the OP's requirement is incorrect and that instead their data needs fixing. They make it clear that `INITCAP`'s behaviour is not what they require.

Comment: I have no problem with the requirement. I questioned the data model itself. The OP can clarify where they are using apostrophes; the requirement would certainly make more sense for an input like ANDRE' LAME' which should be changed to Andre' Lame' (really: input should be ANDRÉ LAMÉ changing to André Lamé, which Initcap can do perfectly well). It does not make sense for the input CE'NEDRA O'BRIEN; the output from that should be Ce'Nedra O'Brien, which is exactly what Initcap does - not Ce'nedra O'brien. With the proper data model, the OP would not have the task he does have now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause to find the alphabetic characters after each white-space character and change them to upper-case:

```sql
WITH bounds (value, pos) AS (
  SELECT UPPER(SUBSTR(value, 1, 1)) || LOWER(SUBSTR(value, 2)),
         REGEXP_INSTR(LOWER(value), '\s([a-z])', 2)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTR(value, 1, pos)
         || UPPER(SUBSTR(value, pos + 1, 1))
         || SUBSTR(value, pos + 2),
         REGEXP_INSTR(LOWER(value), '\s([a-z])', pos + 2)
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  pos > 0
)
SELECT value
FROM   bounds
WHERE  pos = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS 
SELECT 'RAKE''SH RE''DD''Y' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE |
> | --- |
> | Rake'sh Re'dd'y |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d4af524b3e80594d6efcc0c6ea40bf5d)*